# common.jar file not found in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am having following error while Generating Signed APK

> EmptyThrowable: Cannot add common.jar from plugin 'Android Support' to
>   external compiler classpath: library D:\Android
>   Studio\plugins\android\lib\common.jar not found

Answer (score 1):

this is a bug in AS 2.2 Preview 5. 
see this:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215501